# Can I convert/read jrprint files

Tags: conversion

I have an epos system that churns out .jrprint files

Can I view/print/convert these files ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the .jprint itself: no.

Those files are from JasperReports (that is a java based open source programming library) and are created as the result of combining data from a data source and a XML definition (.jrxml; you can use iReport to make those). The .jprint that is created is then used to create a .PDF, .XLS, .CSV, .RTF, .TXT, .XML, and/or .HTML.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind. How then do I convert to, say, pdf?

Comment: Probably not possible without jasperreports; you need the tools they make and those are not command line + the expect you to have the corresponding .jrxml.